# Access ActionView on Android ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have a problem getting the actionview from a menu item used in an actionbar. 
I'm using Actionbarsherlock for compatibility reasons.

I'm using this code in onCreateOptionMenu:

```
        menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search)
        .setActionView(R.layout.collapsible_edittext)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
```

The ActionView i set is just an EditText from XML which will "fill_parent" in terms of width.
As i couldn't find a way to access this edittext to register an event handler i tried to inflate "R.layout.collapsible_edittext" in oncreateoptionsmenu (and later in onOptionsItemSelected) adding the result as acitonview.
After i did this i could access the edittext but it didn't take the full width in my actionbar anymore after the icon was clicked.

Any hints how to access the ActionView properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EditText layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:hint="Search"/>
```

Code

```
 private EditText search;


  private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //... your logic here    
        }
    };

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, 3, 3, R.string.ac_search  ).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search).setActionView(R.layout.action_search).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case 3:
                search = (EditText) item.getActionView();
                search.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
                break;

        }
        return true;
    }
```